# корень N-ой степени в sagemath

Tags: python, sage

надо найти производную корня 4 степени от х, можно записать как x^1/4, но хотелось бы знать, есть ли возможность выразить на python в этой формулировке. Я пробывал так `diff(sqrt(x)^4)`. Но не получаю ожидаемого результата.

Comment: так пробовали: `diff(x^(1/4), x)` или `diff(x**(1/4), x)`?

Comment: @MaxU попробовал, все равно ответ не тот. При diff(sqrt(x)^4, x) и diff(sqrt(x)^4, x, 1) ответ '2x', а должен быть 1/4x^3/4

Comment: @MaxU суть вопроса не в том, что бы изменить формулировку и записать как diff(x^1/4), а с использованием sqrt()

Comment: хммм... а каким образом у вас `1/4x^3/4` - получается? Вы ищете производную от `diff( (x^(1/2))^4 ) = diff( x^2 ) = 2x`

Comment: @MaxU производная от x^1/4 = 1/4x^3/4, а производная от (x^1/4)^4 = 2x. Мне нужен первый вариант

Comment: вы можете записать фразу `квадратного кореня в 4 степени` в виде математического выражения? или вы имели в виду `x` в степени `1/4` ?

Comment: если вам всенепременно надо использовать функцию __квадратного__ корня, то можно так: `diff(sqrt(sqrt(x)))`

Comment: @MaxU мне надо записать **квадратный корень в 4 степени от x**

Comment: @MaxU **diff(sqrt(sqrt(x)))** тоже не то, но спасибо за старания

Comment: вы взрываете мне мозг - `квадратный корень в 4 степени от x` - это `x^2`

Comment: @MaxU (http://ru.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Csqrt%5B4%5D%7Bx%7D%5Cright))

Comment: я же вам в самом начале дал ответ: `diff(x^(1/4))` (`"x^(1/4)"` - читается как `"корень четвертой степени от x"`). вы же пытаетесь использовать формулу __квадратного__ корня (`sqrt()`).

Comment: @MaxU **...надо найти производную квадратного кореня в 4 степени от х, можно записать как x^1/4 ...** , интерес был в том можно ли выразить это не как diff(x^1/4) а с помощью метода sqrt() или какого нибудь другого

Comment: `"x в степени 1/4"` в Python - `pow(x, 1/4)` или `x**(1/4)`

Comment: @MaxU тоже как вариант, спасибо. Но это идентично x^1/4 или x**1/4. И думаю стоит извинится за неправильное использование терминологии.

Answer (score 2):

Корень четвёртой степени можно получить так:

```
sqrt(sqrt(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

python:
pow(pow(2, 100), 1/100) #2.0 = 100√(2^100)

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что

- `sqrt(x)^4` то есть $(\sqrt{x})^4$ то есть $x^2$
- корень 4-ой степени можно написать

  - `x^(1/4)`
  - или `real_nth_root(x, 4)`
  - или по ответ @Qwertiy♦: `sqrt(sqrt(x))`

В SageMath 9.2:

```
sage: diff(x^(1/4), x)
1/4/x^(3/4)

sage: diff(real_nth_root(x, 4), x)
1/4*real_nth_root(x^(-3), 4)

sage: diff(sqrt(sqrt(x)), x)
1/4/x^(3/4)
```

```
sage: sqrt(81)^4
6561
sage: sqrt(81)
9
sage: 9^4
6561

sage: 3^4
81
sage: 81^(1/4)
3
sage: real_nth_root(81, 4)
3
sage: sqrt(sqrt(81))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pow(x, 1/n) #корень N-ной степени n√x
pow(1267650600228229401496703205376, 1/100) #корень сотой степени: 2.0 = 100√(2^100)
```

Comment: Добавить описание.